# ng-if in dir-paginate passes undefined even when object is defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this `dir-paginate` line:

```
<tr class="table-rw-hover" dir-paginate="historyEntry in HistoryLog | orderBy:sort:reverse | itemsPerPage: 10" ng-if="isRequiredRoleToView(historyEntry.RequiredRoleToView)">
```

I've verified that there are no null entries in `HistoryLog`, but the `historyEntry.RequiredRoleToView` parameter always comes through as undefined to my `isRequiredRoleToView` function.

```
        $scope.isRequiredRoleToView = function (requiredRoleToView) {
            console.log(requiredRoleToView); //always undefined

            if (CurrentUser.Role === 'ADMN') {
                return true;
            }

            if (requiredRoleToView) {
                return (CurrentUser.Role === requiredRoleToView.Role);
            }

            return false;
        };
```

I tried modifying the `ng-if` to pass the parent `historyEntry` object instead and it also comes through as undefined. If I pass the entire `HistoryLog` collection to the function it comes through fine and everything is populated. My guess is that there's some problem in the way `dir-paginate` is enumerating the collection.

I use `dir-paginate` and `ng-if` in a similar fashion elsewhere and it works fine:

```
<tr class="table-rw-hover" dir-paginate="referenceMaterial in ReferenceMaterials | orderBy:sort:reverse | itemsPerPage: 10" ng-if="referenceMaterial.DeletedOnDate == null">
```

I've even tried reducing the `ng-if` to `ng-if="historyEntry"` and it always evaluates to false. But if I `console.log(HistoryLog)` it shows 17 fully populated entries and no nulls.

-- EDIT --

I replaced the `dir-paginate` directive with `ng-repeat` and everything comes through just fine, so it looks like the problem is with `dir-paginate`. Unfortunately this kills my pagination.

```
<tr class="table-rw-hover" ng-repeat="historyEntry in HistoryLog | orderBy:sort:reverse" ng-if="isRequiredRoleToView(historyEntry.RequiredRoleToView)">
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that an `ng-if` directive on the same line as the `dir-paginate` can accept a parameter you're looping through. I think that's why it's coming through as undefined. I'd also double check your second example to ensure that `referenceMaterial` isn't actually undefined and is causing your `ng-if` statement to evaluate to true because the object is undefined.

Comment: @BenBeck I replaced `dir-paginate` with `ng-repeat` and it works, but it kills my pagination. So problem seems to be with `dir-paginate`.

Comment: After some research, it looks like this bug once existed with dir-paginate, but was patched. Can you ensure you're using the newest version of this library?

Comment: @BenBeck I just grabbed the latest off of github but the problem persists. Can you show me where you found evidence that it was patched?

Comment: https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/commit/716ac51ce37bbb2d548d2503505fb76d102254b9

Comment: Did you find solution to this problem? @Legion